# Best way to add a SKPhysicsJoint to an object

Tags: ios, physics, sprite-kit

So I have a marionette I am making in Sprite Kit, and placing him in a scene. I have created a Marionette class, which is a subclass of SKNode, and when I create an instance of this class, I add a number of SKSpriteNodes to each other. This should give you an idea of how it works (I've snipped out the unnecessary lines):

```
[self addChild:self.head];
[self.head addChild:self.chest];
[self.chest addChild:self.leftLeg];
[self.chest addChild:self.rightLeg];
[self.leftLeg addChild:self.leftFoot];
[self.rightLeg addChild:self.rightFoot];
```

So, after doing this, I have my marionette showing up. I want to add a SKPhysicsJointPin to each of these connections. Code looks like this:

```
self.chestPin = [SKPhysicsJointPin jointWithBodyA:self.marionette.head.physicsBody bodyB:self.marionette.chest.physicsBody anchor:self.marionette.chest.anchorPoint];
```

At first I thought I could just set up all the pins inside the Marionette class, but that doesn't work (I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS if I recall). It turns out that I have to add the Marionette to the overall SKScene before I add the joints.

This make sense I guess, but I can't help thinking there should be some way I could just set everything up in the Marionette class, and then stick 2 lines of code in the scene to create a new Marionette, then addChild him to the Scene.

As it is, my SKScene subclass has a bunch of code now to add all the pins, and it doesn't feel like it fits in the Scene. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to use `anchorPoint` as anchor. The anchorPoint property is a factor which ranges from 0 to 1 and affects how the texture is offset from the sprite's position, ie the default 0.5/0.5 centers the sprite's texture on the sprite's position. In other words `anchorPoint` is not a position, and using that will anchor the body & head joint to the lower left corner of the screen.

Instead try using either chest or head's position as anchor, or the point in between the two.

Comment: Hey, so what I was doing was, I was setting the anchorPoint of each node like this: self.chest.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.0); so I could use that point in each body part to pin it to another body part. Then I was pinning them using the anchorPoint of the body part NOT the scene. Cause I actually am confused as to why that would anchor them to the lower left corner of the screen. (one of the code snippets in my post didn't make this clear, just edited it)

Comment: Okay, anchorPoint doesn't necessarily mean lower left corner of the screen. It could also mean "slightly offset from parent's position". In any way, the anchorPoint does not return a position, it returns the 0.5, 0.0 factors. Which means the joint's anchor is at self.marionette.parent.position where x is slightly offset by 0.5. This isn't what you intend to do, right?

Comment: self.marionette.chest.parent.position to be precise, or simply marionette's position if chest is a child of marionette.